# How to compare Histogram Data?

Tags: histograms, dataset

I'm using a `Dataset`

```
ds = Dataset@*Map[AssociationThread[{"ID", "Date", "Value1", "Value2", 
    "Value3"} -> #] &]@
{{"C9",SQLDateTime[{2012, 12, 11, 0, 0, 0.}], 1., 31., 37.}, 
{"C9",SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 22, 0, 0, 0.}], 1., 139., 31.},
{"C9",SQLDateTime[{2013, 2, 19, 19, 30, 0.}], Null, 720., 19.},
{"C9",SQLDateTime[{2013, 3, 8, 19, 40, 0.}], Null, 720., 28.},
{"C9",SQLDateTime[{2013, 4, 2, 21, 50, 0.}], Null, 720., 42.},
{"C10",SQLDateTime[{2012, 12, 12, 0, 2, 0.}], 1., 30., 33.},
{"C10",SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 28, 9, 25, 0.}], 1., 123.9, 40.},
{"C10",SQLDateTime[{2013, 3, 21, 20, 0, 0.}], Null, 720., 23.},
{"C10",SQLDateTime[{2013, 5, 24, 19, 45, 0.}], Null, 786., 40.},
{"C10",SQLDateTime[{2013, 6, 1, 17, 0, 0.}], Null, 786.2, 35.},
{"C11",SQLDateTime[{2012, 12, 10, 10, 0, 0.}], 1., 30., 27.},
{"C11",SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 23, 20, 50, 0.}], 1., 139., 32.},
{"C11",SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 25, 21, 0, 0.}], 2, 720., 41.},
{"C11",SQLDateTime[{2013, 4, 24, 20, 35, 0.}], Null, 732., 42.},
{"C11",SQLDateTime[{2013, 5, 4, 22, 0, 0.}], Null, 786., 18.},
{"C11",SQLDateTime[{2013, 8, 27, 6, 40, 0.}], Null, 720., 28.}}
```

and produce a group of histograms by

```
hist = ds[GroupBy[Key["Value1"]], Histogram[#, {15, 45, 5}] &,"Value3"]
```

[image]

I know, that I can display one of these Histograms like here:
[image]

My question is now, how to compare two of these histograms? For instance via `PairedHistogram` in order to make them better comparable. But neither with `PairedHistogram` nor like this:
    `Histogram[{ha,hb}]` 
it works.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: `Histogram` is for plotting.  To get the data instead, you might want to use `HistogramList` or `BinCounts`.

Comment: @Szabolcs I reformulated my question. I don't want to get the data, but compare the histograms in a graphical way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps

```
PairedHistogram[Sequence@@#, {15,45,5}]&/@
      Subsets[Normal@(Values@ds[GroupBy[Key["Value1"]],All,"Value3"]),{2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works! Even if I did not understand your suggestion in every detail at the moment, I have still a lot to learn.

Comment: Especially the `Normal` did help me a lot, since with its help I can use the data also with more than one datasets in `Histogram`.